# Cant set breakpoint in C++/Objective-C++ code

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++

I'm trying to set a breakpoint in my objective c++ ( I think its called) code.

I've used `#ifdef _cplusplus` and `#endif` to wrap the code, but when I go to set a breakpoint in it, it breaks on the end of the method body, and none of the code in the body is run.

[image: Bad breakpoints :/]

I've simplified the code I had, but I expect at least to see numbers being printed in the console because of the `cout`.

The file has the extension .mm too. I'm new to mixing C++ and Objective-C. Anything I've missed?

Comment: If it's not the ifdef, has your code raised an exception?  If you run on, what happens?

Comment: if I run on, I don't see any numbers in the console, as you would expect to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#ifdef` is a [preprocessor directive](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) - in short, this means that without `_cplusplus` being `#define`d somewhere, your debugger is smart enough to say *Hey, this is dead code - don't even try to debug it*.

> Preprocessor directives are lines included in the code of programs
>   preceded by a hash sign (#). These lines **are not program statements**
>   but directives for the *preprocessor*. The preprocessor examines the
>   code before actual compilation of code begins and resolves all these
>   directives before any code is actually generated by regular
>   statements.
>
> These preprocessor directives extend only across a single line of
>   code. As soon as a newline character is found, the preprocessor
>   directive is ends. No semicolon (;) is expected at the end of a
>   preprocessor directive. The only way a preprocessor directive can
>   extend through more than one line is by preceding the newline
>   character at the end of the line by a backslash ().

These are super useful, and for a common example have a quick look at [Include Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). As a test to see what I mean, try adding `#define _cplusplus` directly above the `#ifdef` and try again.

Comment: So is there a way for xcode to be able to debug this code without removing the preprocessor directives (that silence build errors)?

Comment: Sure, just add a `#define _cplusplus` *before the `#ifdef` check*; don't remove anything. But I'm not sure what you mean by 'that silence build errors'. If you've added the preprocessor directives to silence your errors, that doesn't mean your code is fixed - it just means that your compiler is ignoring that chunk, and not even *attempting* to compile it.

Comment: Ah, bugger. Yeah, I assumed the compile error I was seeing was because it wasn't known it was C++. I took out all the directives and fixed the compile error, and we're good.